# Supplying a second file with same name as makefile target

Tags: html, makefile, cat

I'm having trouble searching for answers because I don't know the terminology to use, but so far all my searching has failed me.  I have the following setup:

- `prependix.html` contains the `<html>` tag, `<head>...</head>` and the various links to CSS files, etc.
- `appendix.html` contains the closing tags for most things, i.e. `</html>` etc.
- Then I have a list of files in a `content/` directory, with things like `foo.html` which is basically just the `<body>...</body>` snippet that I generate from emacs org mode via pandoc.

Here is the makefile I currently use:

```
CXX=cat
CXXPRE=templates/prependix.html
CXXPOST=templates/appendix.html
TARGETS=staging/index.html staging/foo.html staging/bar.html staging/baz.html staging/quux.html
    
default: $(TARGETS)

stage1/%.html: content/%.org
    mkdir -p stage1/
    pandoc $< -o $@

staging/%.html: stage1/%.html
    mkdir -p staging/
    $(CXX) $(CXXPRE) $< $(CXXPOST) > $@

clean:
    rm -rf staging/
    rm -rf stage1/

deploy:
    mkdir -p staging/css
    cp content/css/styles.css staging/css/
    mkdir -p staging/img
    cp content/img/*.png staging/img/
    cp content/img/*.jpg staging/img/
    rsync -a --delete staging/ $(URI):/home/me/www/mysite.tld
```

That makefile works, but what I realized is that I can't specify per-file `<meta>` tags, and I would like to do so.  So I will split the prependix into two and and provide e.g. `foo.meta`, `bar.meta`, etc. which will contain just the `<meta>` tags. If I were doing a single concatenation on the command line I would perform it as such:

`$ cat templates/prependix.html foo.meta templates/prependix2.html foo.html templates/appendix.html > final-product.html`

As a make rule, something like:

`$(CXX) $(CXXPRE) [somehow specify the .meta file here] $(CXXPRE2) $< $(CXXPOST) > $@`

How can I do this?  Is it even possible?

Comment: does the solution I provided works for you.

Comment: Can you indicate more clearly how you want the different meta files applied to different html files? Do you want `foo.mets` for `foo.html` alone? Or `bar.meta` for `index.html` and `baz.html`, or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find below code which will solve the issue.
You can put all your .meta files in the stage1 folder. Example: stage1/foo.meta and use `stage1/$(*).meta` . This will be realised as stage1/foo.meta

```
CXX=cat
CXXPRE=templates/prependix.html
CXXPOST=templates/appendix.html
TARGETS=staging/index.html staging/foo.html staging/bar.html staging/baz.html staging/quux.html
    
default: $(TARGETS)

stage1/%.html: content/%.org
    mkdir -p stage1/
    pandoc $< -o $@

# You can add dependency stage1/%.meta if needed or remove it as per your need
staging/%.html: stage1/%.meta stage1/%.html
    mkdir -p staging/
    $(CXX) $(CXXPRE) stage1/$(*).meta $< $(CXXPOST) > $@

clean:
    rm -rf staging/
    rm -rf stage1/

deploy:
    mkdir -p staging/css
    cp content/css/styles.css staging/css/
    mkdir -p staging/img
    cp content/img/*.png staging/img/
    cp content/img/*.jpg staging/img/
    rsync -a --delete staging/ $(URI):/home/me/www/mysite.tld
```

Please note the above was just an example to give you a redable and working solution.
Also based on Raspy comments you can replace `stage1/$(*).meta with $(word 2, $^)$(CXXPOST) > $@` , both will give the same results but avoid discrepancies between dependency and recipe

Comment: Better yet this should depend also on meta file, i.e. `staging/%.html: stage1/%.html stage1/%.meta` and invoke as `$(CXX) $(CXXPRE) $(word 2, $^) $< $(CXXPOST) > $@`. This would cause regeneration of target file should the metafile change.

Comment: @raspy : yes you can add dependecy as per your need. `staging/%.html: stage1/%.html  stage1/%.meta
    mkdir -p staging/
    $(CXX) $(CXXPRE) stage1/$(*).meta $< $(CXXPOST) > $@`

Comment: Still recommend replacing `stage1/$(*).meta` with `$(word 2, $^)` to fulfill [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) rule and avoid discrepancies between dependency and recipe.

Comment: This required a bit of massaging to make it work, but it solved my problem.  Thanks!  I will note that `$(word 2, $^)` and `$<` match the same thing on my system, so I ended up using `$(word 1, $^)` and `$(word 2, $^)`.  I also added a subrule for building `stage1/%.meta` out of the `content/` directory.